# (GIGABYTE BIOS) PS/2 keyboard isn't working, but is seen in devmgmt

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, motherboard, bios, ps2

## Backstory:

I have a new PC build, and it's my first time using a GIGABYTE motherboard; model: `Z270XP-SLI`.  It's on the latest `F9d` BIOS revision.  When I use my Rosewill RK9000 PS/2 keyboard with it, I get Lock lights, and everything appears to work, but none of the inputs are recognized from BIOS (or OS, obviously).

## Troubleshooting:

I thankfully had a backup USB keyboard and it works as expected.  Weird thing: when I turn on/off a Lock on the USB keyboard, the PS/2 keyboard's Lock state also changes.  The PS/2 keyboard is seen in Win10's device manager, drivers are reportedly up-to-date.  Additionally, if I unplug/re-plug the PS/2 keyboard, it starts working (required after every reboot)!  A weird quirk I've noticed, though, is n-key rollover doesn't appear to be working and holding down a button doesn't send a stream of inputs, but seems.. delayed (especially noticeable when deleting text).

## Question:

Is there a known issue with GIGABYTE motherboards and PS/2 devices or am I missing a BIOS configuration (worst BIOS I've ever worked with as a tech professional) somewhere that would resolve my problems described here?  All I could find describing this are posts recommending BIOS resets or disabling USB mice, from 2005 (literally).

---

*Additional info*: After more experimentation, even though the OS is seeing the PS/2 keyboard and loading the correct generic drivers, it seems the BIOS is seeing it as a pseudo-USB keyboard (only have 3-key rollover and inputs are limited by the bus).

How it *is* running like PS/2, however, is during the boot process.  If I start the PC without it plugged in, the OS will not identify it after plugging it in unless it boots with it plugged in (which I have to unplug/replug like described above to work).  Also, turning on Fast Boot and checking the PS/2 option makes no difference.

Comment: Try these. BIOS > Fastboot: Enabled (Don't set to Ultra Fast), BIOS > PS2 Devices Support: Enabled, Peripherals > USB Configuration > Port 60/64 Emulation: Disabled.

Comment: @guest Gave that a shot- still isn't working.

Comment: Thank for your feedback but I'm unable to provide further help on this.